# How to pass text dynamically in xpath under Properties file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, properties-file

I am stuck in a situation where I want to write Xpath dynamically in the properties file. The actual XPath is like in property File `div[contains(text(),'<state Name>')]`. State Name changes everytime. How can I write dynamic xpath which fetches from property file?

below is Xpath stored in properties file

```
data=div[contains(text(),'New Delhi')]
```

and below code snippet is fetching xpath in test script

```
String checkCity=prop.getProperty(data) ; 
WebElement xpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write dynamic xpath using format method of String class of Java.

Properties file :
data=div[contains(text(),'%s')]

Script code :

```
String checkCity=prop.getProperty(data) ; 
WebElement xpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(checkCity,"New Delhi")));
```